# What is the equvelent of mvn eclipse plugin for ant?

Tags: eclipse, ant

I have an unwieldy ant project from another team that I would like to work on in eclipse. Is there an equivalent to maven's eclipse:eclipse command for ant?

I can import it into eclipse manually but there are a number of steps required which I need to do to get it working properly in eclipse and I would like to automate those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've inherited someone else's code, and want to get started quickly, I'd suggest the [ANT2IDE](http://gleamynode.net/articles/2234/ant2ide-ide-project-file-generation-from-ant-buildxml) project. Doesn't require any updates to the build, because it cleverly uses an ANT build listener to determine the jars used by the *javac* task.

If you've got time to refactor the build, I'd suggest using [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage the dependencies. There is an [Eclipse plugin](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/) available.

Answer (score 1):

Ant is pretty baked into Eclipse, so there is no separate plugin for it, it just comes with the basic and JDT support.

I think the best you can do (and I'm not sure how good it will be) is to Create the project like this: `New -> Project -> Java -> Java Project from Existing Buildfile`.

Comment: Thanks, This is where I am at. I am looking more for an Ant plugin for eclipse rather than an eclipse plugin for ant.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eclipse wizard to create Java project from an existing Ant fuildfile. See "File / New / Project... / Java / Java Project from Existing Ant Buildfile".